# How to check an ability of swift to open URL?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, url

I'm trying to get all the images from web and can't correctly check validity of the url. My code:

```
    var url = NSURL(string: self.linkUrl)
    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url!) {
        errorLabel.hidden = true
        println(self.resultUrl)
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Save", sender: self)
    } else {
        errorLabel.hidden = false
    }
```

It works if the user pastes something like "https://www.google.com" but it doesn't if it's "www.google.com" or "google.com". I've also tried:

```
    if var url = NSURL(string: self.linkUrl) {
        errorLabel.hidden = true
        println(self.resultUrl)
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Save", sender: self)
    } else {
        errorLabel.hidden = false
    }
```

It works if i enter "https://www.google.com" but on "www.google.com" and "google.com" the code breaks further when I'm searching for images in html.
What's the best way to make it work ?

Comment: an URL needs to know its protocol... if you enter www.google.com it is only the address, but how should your app know how to access? ftp, telnet, ssh, http...

Answer (score 1):

`www.google.com` is not a valid URL, because it doesn't include a [protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator#Syntax). The best way to make it work is simply to check if `self.linkURL` starts with `http://` or `https://` (using [`hasPrefix()`](https://developer.apple.com/library//ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/index.html)), and if not, prepend `http://`.